# MS ACCESS integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint;

Tags: java, html, sql, jsp, servlets

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<HTML>
<BODY>
<form method="post" >

    Name:<input type="text" name="userName"><br>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br>
    Email Id:<input type="text" name="email"><br>
    Language: <select name="language">
        <option>Hindi</option>
        <option>English</option>
        <option>French</option>
    </select> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>


<%
String n = request.getParameter("userName");
String p = request.getParameter("password");
String e = request.getParameter("email");
String c = request.getParameter("language");


try {

Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

Connection con=        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/eclipse/register.accdb","","");

PreparedStatement ps = con
        .prepareStatement("insert into USERDETAILS values(?,?,?,?)");

ps.setString(1, n);
ps.setString(2, p);
ps.setString(3, e);
ps.setString(4, c);

int i= ps.executeUpdate();
if (i > 0) {
     out.print("You are successfully registered...");   
}

else{
    out.println("failed");
}


} catch (Exception e2) {
System.out.println(e2);
}  
%>

</BODY>
</html>
```

Every time I run this code in Eclipse the following message appears at console, but my database get updated

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_PK_10174 table: USERDETAILS column: NAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting to the database on page load before the form is submitted. Thus parameters are `null`. You should set the `action` attribute to another page or better servlet which should perform updates via executing java and sql codes and then redirect to the view page. You need not `null` values to insert to the database because constraint is enabled to not allow `NULL` values.

```
<form action="yourpage.jsp" method="post" >
```